# MongoDB failed to start on Widnows 7 SP1 Machine

Tags: mongodb

Can't Start mongoDB on Windows 7 SP1 Machine..

```
2017-08-24T11:46:10.280+0300 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] listen(): bind() failed
An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket. for socket: 0.0.
0.0:27017

2017-08-24T11:46:10.281+0300 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to set up sockets
 during startup.

2017-08-24T11:46:10.281+0300 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up listene
r: InternalError: Failed to set up sockets
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you can run the following command to check whether the port **27017** is accessible or open for connections.

```
netstat -a -n | find "27017"
```

This will let you know if the MongoDB port is available for connection.

Alternately, you could open Task Manager and close all the open `mongod` processes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help. But the port is free for connections and taskManager shows no processes running associated to mongoDB. Any other recommendations?